# Add text before command in bash

Tags: bash

```
COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
weather="Temperature${IFS}"$(<weather)
curl -s 'wttr.in/Boston?format=%t' > weather.txt
printf " %*s\n" $(((${#weather}+$COLUMNS)/2)) $weather | pv -qL 80
```

Desired output: `[ Temperature is (temperature) ]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `echo "[ Temperature is $(curl -s 'wttr.in/Boston?format=%t') ]"`?

Comment: Is the temperature calculated from `$(((${#weather}+$COLUMNS)/2)) $weather`?

Comment: @ChritopherMoore : You forgot to output the words _Temperature is_ ...

Comment: Can you show your actual output?

Comment: printf: +34°F: invalid number
                                                                         Temperature

Comment: You seem to be reading from a file named "weather", and *then* storing the temperature to a file named "weather.txt". Aside from the name mismatch, you can't read what you haven't written yet. Also, `$IFS` normally consists of a space, a tab character, and a newline character; is that really what you want between the text and the temperature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quote `$weather` in your last line so printf. Therefore `Temperature` and `+34°F` will be two parameters for printf.

This should work:

```
printf " %*s\n" $(((${#weather}+$COLUMNS)/2)) "$weather" | pv -qL 80
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time!

Comment: Any way to remove degree symbol?

Comment: If you only want to replace the degree symbol try `"${weather/°}"`. If you want to remove everything after the degree symbol as well try `"${weather/°*}"`.

Comment: Wow.
Thank you so much

Comment: Then replace weather before the printf statement => `weather="${weather/°*}"`

Comment: remove space from " %*s\n"